# vue.js api connection to MySQL, using axios and proxyTables

Tags: php, api, vue-cli

Trying to connect to a local MySQL database using an api in vue.js

This project is run in a directory in my home directory, and not in `~/Sites` or `/Library/WebServer/Documentation/` which are the usual public directories on a MAC.

The **api.php** file connection to the db,

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli("localhost:3306", "root", "", "vuephpcrud");

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Could not connect to database!");
}

$res = array('error' => false);
$action = 'read';
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    $action = $_GET['action'];
}


if($action == 'read'){
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
    $users = array();

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        array_push($users, $row);
    }

    $res['users'] = $users;
}
```

**api.php** retrieves data from the db if I use the default php server,

```
$ php -S localhost:8080
```

and navigate to,

```
localhost:8080/api.php?action=read
```

The api.php file is in the root of the vue project.

But if I running the dev server I can not get anything from the db,

```
$ npm run dev
```

navigating to,

```
localhost:8080/api.php?action=read
```

gives me,

[image]

I am using axios,

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
  mounted: function(){
    console.log("mounted");
    this.getAllUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    getAllUsers: function(){
      axios.get("http://localhost/api.php?action=read")
      .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        if(response.data.error){
          app.errorMessage = response.data.message;
        } else {
          app.users = response.data.users;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

But actually that is not relevant here as I am navigating directly in the browser.

I think I need to use [ProxyTables](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/proxy.html),

config/index.js

```
proxyTable: {
      // proxy all requests starting with / api to api.php
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read',
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          '^/api': ''
        }
      }
    },
```

then navigating to

localhost:8080/api/

this gives me,

```
Error occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:8080.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/
```

But no errors in the console.

Comment: Have you tried either adding the port number to your axios-call `axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read")` or better yet, changing it to a relative path from the doc root: `axios.get("/api.php?action=read")`

Comment: `http://location:8080/` and `http://location/` are two different URL:s

Comment: using axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read") in the console I get xhr.js?ec6c:178 GET http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read 404 (Not Found) thanks for looking at this

Comment: I changed to this axios.get("/api.php?action=read") and get this GET http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read 404 (Not Found) which is the same error thanks

Comment: I added proxytable info in config/index.js this has been added to the original post

Comment: Your code is trying to access: `localhost:8080.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/.php?action=read/`. I have no idea what you've done here.

Comment: Yes ok I see that now. What I did was added the proxytable. I will get rid of that now.

Comment: I am not using the proxyTable bit. Using axios.get("/api.php?action=read") I should be able to console.log(response) Why does this not work?

Comment: I have tried each of these two and each give the same error:     axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api.php?action=read")  axios.get("/api.php?action=read") Also i tried axios.get("http://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes")  and it works and I can console.log(repsonse.data) so why is it not working when i try to connect to db? The proxytable {} object is empty in config/index.js.